# Electron.js How to implement floating Desktop icon button with half hidden on screen border

Tags: electron, window, desktop-application, desktop, floating-action-button

I want to create this feature in electron desktop app.
I need to make one clickable icon image on click of that icon it will open a new window above that icon.
Apart from this requirement i need that icon should be floatable anywhere in the screen as well as when that icon is near to any end (left, right, bottom, top) it should stick with border with half hidden.

Comment: You could look to Jquery draggable.. or do your own mouse event handler when the target is your icon containe.